# subscripted assignment ignoring NAs

Tags: r, slice

I have a scoring matrix which I want to normalize. In order to do that, I simply want to divide all negative values by the minimum value and all positive ones by the maximum one (which conveniently makes every value positive and between 0 and 1, with two ones in the matrix).

This would nicely do, if there weren’t NAs.

```
scores[scores < 0] <- scores[scores < 0] / min(scores, rm.na=T)
scores[scores > 0] <- scores[scores > 0] / max(scores, rm.na=T)
scores
```

I just want to ignore the NAs and treat them as FALSE. `min` and `max` already nicely deal with NAs when specified, but is there a way to make `<`/`>` behave like that, too?

e.g. the following applies:

```
 1 NA             T T
NA  2   >  0  ==  T T
-1 -2             F F
```

How to do

```
 1 NA             T F
NA  2   ?  0  ==  F T
-1 -2             F F
```

Comment: Since your logic checks don't include `0` you could convert all `NA` values to `0`.   Or use `scores[scores < 0 & !is.na(scores)]`.

Comment: ah thanks! so `&` *does* replace NAs with TRUEs. not pretty, though: `scores[scores < 0 & !is.na(scores)] <- scores[scores < 0 & !is.na(scores)] / min(scores, na.rm=T)`

Comment: and of course i don’t need to replaces zeros with something that’s guaranteed to be zero, too, but i need to keep the NAs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a more complex boolean condition:

```
x <- scores < 0 & !is.na(scores)

scores[x] <- scores[x] / min(scores[x])
```